# Triggering a relay with a 0.7 - 2 Hz pulsating DC voltage between 0 and 12 V

Tags: relay, dc, filter, automotive, square

50% duty cycle. I would prefer if there was a passive solution to this but it's not a necessity. The relay needs to turn on when the signal is pulsating and to turn off when the signal is no longer pulsating after 2 seconds.

Comment: Welcome. Assuming the pulse turns it on and someting else turns it off I would suggest a latching relay. It would turn with the first pulse and not turn off until you trigger the off coil. You will need a high duty cycle for this cycle rate. Consider a solid state switch. The switch would turn on and off with the pulse. No idea of what the load is so no suggestion. This would turn on and off with the pulse no wear out mechanisms like you would have with a relay.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Following a pulse which activates the relay, how long do you want the relay activated for? In other words, for how long should the pulses be *absent* (none detected), before you decide that the relay should be off?

Comment: Let's say 2 seconds before it detects that the pulse is absent

Comment: @AshKetchup Would you need to exclude anything at a higher rate than 2 Hz? Or would 5 Hz still be acceptable? Would 20 Hz be acceptable? Etc.

Comment: @periblepsis 5Hz would be acceptable but the signal will never really reach any frequency above about 2Hz

Comment: @AshKetchup Well, that simplifies things a lot. Just need a retriggerable circuit. Need details about the relay and details about the "pulsing DC." For example, is both the relay and the pulsing DC 12 V? You don't write very much and it would help a lot to see more from you.

Comment: @periblepsis Sorry for the confusion, Ive been toying around with a monostable retriggerable circuit using a 555 timer, but in my simulations I see a drop in output voltage to the relay around 5-10 seconds in. The relay just needs to trigger when it senses the pulsating 12VDC to allow a secondary constant 12v DC source to flow to a light. I'm sorry if this doesnt help I'm not quite exactly sure what you are asking.

Comment: @periblepsis The circuit I am currently simulating is the missing pulse detector, Figure 15, on page 11. https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/attachments/ne555_texas-pdf.124768/

Comment: @AshKetchup I can't visit that site as I haven't signed up for it. I wanted to know if the relay is a 12 V relay (70 Ohm typical for the coil) and if the triggering voltage "pulses" were also 12 V and that you wanted retriggering on the rising edge (or is it the falling edge?) More details. (To see it from my side: Look at your question. Count the number of words. Count the number of pictures, diagrams, tables, and illustrations.) You've now mentioned using a 555. Does this mean you don't want a discrete solution? Etc.

Comment: @periblepsis Ideally I would prefer to if it were passive but its not completely necessary.  The relay is a 12v relay and the pulses are also 12VDC. I would like to trigger it by the rising edge. I'm sorry I dont know how to add pictures.

Comment: @AshKetchup What's the relay current?

Comment: @periblepsis 30mA

Comment: @AshKetchup Thanks. The circuit I've provided can handle twice that and more. So it should be fine.

Comment: Does the input signal have enough current capability to drive the relay coil directly?  If the input signal can source more than 30 mA, there could be a relatively simple solution.  Also, does the relay have to close on the first leading edge of the input, or can the circuit take a few input cycles to decide that there is a valid signal and close the relay?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are asking about a discrete, non-IC solution, then start with this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgWPZ6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's your relay (likely about \$70\:\Omega\$ series resistance) with an included diode to allow its energy to be discharged when turning it **off**. A ground-referenced circuit will then be attached to the top lead.

It's possible to develop an edge-triggered circuit, but this involves more calculations and you have a solid square wave. So I'll consider a simpler approach. Since the relay is likely to require about \$200\:\text{mA}\$ (awaiting your statement about that), I have to assume that your square wave has a current compliance of at least \$2\:\text{mA}\$. (If it is less than this, then what I develop won't be sufficient.)

Next step is to use a standard circuit to operate the relay while the square wave is at \$12\:\text{V}\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Bhm3.png)</sup>

That's not useful to you, yet. But it does operate the relay while the square wave is high. When the square wave goes low, the relay is released. It is this last part that needs work.

Another BJT would do the trick. This one, though, needs to stay enabled for a while:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fac3JZ.png)</sup>

A diode has been added so that the one BJT's collector doesn't directly interfere with the other. (And the diode drop is negligible and is still able to turn the relay **on**.) Some circuit needs to detect when the relay is turned **on** and then do something with a timing and control circuit that will operate the newly added BJT to keep the relay **on** even after the square wave has gone low.

This can be achieved by something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnXhDZ.png)</sup>

When \$Q_1\$ actively pulls up on the relay load, that action also hauls up on \$M_1\$'s gate via \$D_3\$, turning \$M_1\$ **on**. (Any remaining charge on \$C_1\$ at this time will also be discharged by \$D_2\$ and \$D_3\$.) \$M_1\$ will turn on \$Q_3\$, which now also holds the relay **on**.

When \$Q_1\$ no longer is active (the square wave is low, now), \$Q_3\$ continues to hold \$M_1\$ **on** via the now-discharged \$C_1\$. But \$C_1\$ will also now start to charge up via \$R_4\$. Eventually, as \$C_1\$ charges it will push \$M_1\$'s gate downward towards ground and eventually shut \$M_1\$ **off**, given enough time.

This is the required *timing* that you wanted!

Now, if \$Q_1\$ is re-triggered ***before*** \$C_1\$ can turn \$M_1\$ **off**, then \$Q_1\$ will discharge \$C_1\$ via \$D_2\$ and \$D_3\$, restarting the timing process. If not, then the relay will turn **off** and the top end of \$C_1\$ will be hauled down to ground by the relay, itself, causing the bottom end of \$C_1\$ (having remaining charge) to go below ground (negative.) \$D_4\$ will now turn on to allow the remaining charge on \$C_1\$ to be discharged, resetting \$C_1\$ for the next opportunity.

\$D_5\$ is added to protect \$M_1\$'s gate.

To make the above detect the rising edge just add a capacitor and a diode (to protect the BJT base.) I've also added a resistor pull-down (\$R_7\$) to make sure the circuit starts up **off**:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB0zKv.png)</sup>

You'll need to select appropriate transistors. But that's not hard to do.

Here's an LTspice run (two, actually) where the square wave is set to a \$3\:\text{s}\$ period and a \$1.5\:\text{s}\$ period. In the first case the relay drops out before the next trigger event. In the second case the relay holds on, continuously.

[image: xxxx]